# how does Google gmail, docs, etc. get its push-notification of changes?

Tags: ajax, google-docs-api

I would assume that there is an AJAX request on the client side that polls for updates, but it is amazingly tight response.  Can someone provide more insight into any tricks that they may be doing in the protocol?

Comment: I believe gChat uses [Web Sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets) and the rest use [polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_%28computer_science%29) with variable-rate intervals (the more you use it, the more it polls, the longer you idle, the longer the wait duration)

Comment: I like the sound of that solution.  That makes sense and is consistent with my user experience where the responsiveness varies during the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two methods generally used in this case

- Polling: the Javascript code polls the server every (for instance) 10 seconds to see if there is some fresh news to show
- Persistent connection: the XMLHttpRequest request is performed by the client, and the server keeps the connection until there is some news (replies data to client in this case), or if a given time-out is reached - then the client tries again and so on.

Google probably uses the 2nd option, which is replying and updating faster.

Comment: It seems that gmail uses primarily the first method. There is only one connection kept open and it seems to be for chat data. Mail data comes in occasional bursts.

Comment: @MK Usually that 2nd option is for chat, correct. The OP is talking about *amazingly tight responses* this is why I'm tempted to think this is the 2nd option - the poll is unlikely to be set with an internal less than 10 seconds.

Comment: The second option is more commonly known as 'comet'.

Comment: The browser-side comet implementation is available in Closure's BrowserChannel (http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn-history/r144/docs/closure_goog_net_browserchannel.js.html) but the server-side is not available. It may also be worthwhile to look into App Engine's Channel API, which is built in a similar manner: http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/building-real-time-apps-app-engine-feed-api.html

Comment: @JH This is a relevant and valuable information, you should make an answer from it.